# Characterization of the dual of the Lebesgue–Bochner spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, duality-theorems, bochner-spaces

I want to prove following theorem:

> Let X be separable and reflexive Banach space, $1<p<\infty$ than
>   $$
> L^p((0,1),X)^* = L^q((0,1),X^*)
> $$
>   where $\frac1{p}+\frac1{q} = 1$, with representation $v\in  L^q((0,1),X^*), u \in L^p((0,1),X)$
>   $$
> \left<v,u\right> = \int_0^1 \left<v(t),u(t)\right> {\rm d}t.
> $$

I would like to know why I need the reflexivity and separability of $X$. I sketch my proof here, but it seams I do not need neither reflexivity nor separability.

---

Proof sketch:

The hard inclusion is
$$
L^p((0,1),X)^* \subset L^q((0,1),X^*)
$$

So let $v^* \in L^p((0,1),X)^*$ than we want to find $v \in  L^q((0,1),X^*)$ such that 
$$
\left<v^*,u\right>  = \int_0^1 \left<v(t),u(t)\right> {\rm d}t
$$
for all $u \in L^p((0,1),X)$.

I will construct piece-wise constant approximation $v_n$ of $v^*$ in such a way that:
\begin{align}
v_n(t) &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \chi_{(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})}(t) v_n^k \qquad &v_n^k \in X^* \\
\left< v^* , x \chi_{(\frac{k}{n},\frac{k+1}{n})}  \right> &= \frac{1}{n} \left< v_n^k, x \right> \qquad &\forall x \in X
\end{align}
where $\chi_A$ is characteristic function of set $A$.

It should be fairly easy to prove that for any simple function $u\in  L^p((0,1),X)$ 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left< v_n , u \right> = \left< v^* , u \right>,
$$

Now comes the part where I might need reflexivity and separability. I need to show that $v_n$ actually converges to some function $v\in L^q((0,1),X^*)$. I guess there might be some problem with measurability, so the separability of $X$ might be handy but it is not clear to me.

If we know that $v_n$ converges to some function $v\in L^q((0,1),X^*)$ than we know that 
$$
\left<v^*,u\right> = \left<v,u\right>
$$
for all simple functions $u$. Since $\left<v^*,\cdot\right>,\left<v,\cdot\right>$ are both continuous than
$$
\left<v^*,u\right> = \left<v,u\right>
$$
for all functions $u \in L^p((0,1),X)$

---

So the only problem that I see is how to show that $v_n$ converges to some function $v$.

Wild guess is that from reflexivity I can show that $v_n$ converges weakly to $v$ but that gives me only weak measurability of $v$, so I need separability of $X$ to get strong measurability of $v$.

Comment: Of course you don't need separability and reflexivity in order to not prove the stated result. A non-proof does not need any assumptions. I suggest reading a book on the topic; out of what's available online, [Chapter 2 of Pisier's book](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~gilles.pisier/ihp-pisier.pdf) is relevant. So is [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/396278/).

Answer (score 2):

The conclusion of the theorem you want to prove holds if and only if $X^*$ has the Radon–Nikodym property with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $(0,1)$. This is precisely what you need to recover Rademacher's theorem about differentiation of Lipschitz maps from $(0,1)$ to $X^*$. Historically, the first description of $(L_p(X))^*$ was given by Bochner and Taylor:

> S. Bochner and A. E. Taylor, [Linear functionals on certain spaces of abstractly-valued functions](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968472?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), *Ann. of Math.* **39** (1938), 913–944.

They have identified the condition for $X$ which is needed for the identification $(L_p(X))^*\cong L_{p^*}(X^*)$, and it is what we call these days the Radon–Nikodym property.

Separability in your proof is redundant but it makes it easier as you may then apply freely [Pettis' measurability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_measurable_function). As I said, it is not essential though as all reflexive spaces have the Radon–Nikodym property.

See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226243/is-l-qx-complemented-in-l-px).