# Banach space property of parabolic Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, parabolic-pde

Let $X$ be a real Banach space with norm $||\cdot||$. We define for $1<p<\infty$ and $t_1<t_2$, the space $Y=L^p(t_1,t_2;X)$ to be the space of measurable functions $f:(t_1,t_2)\to X$ such that the norm
$$
||f||_{L^p(t_1,t_2;X)}:=\Big(\int_{t_1}^{t_2}||f||_{X}^p\,dt\Big)^\frac{1}{p}<\infty.
$$

My question is whether the space $Y$ is a reflexive Banach space?

Can you kindly help me.

Any reference is alo very much appreciated.

Thanking you.

Comment: You want to look for "Radon-Nikodym property of Banach spaces".

Answer (score 0):

If you use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318668/characterization-of-the-dual-of-the-lebesgue-bochner-spaces), you can show the desired result by applying the result twice provided that X is separable and reflexive.