# About $L^\infty$ in the dual of $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Does someone know where can I find a proof of the following?

$$L^\infty(\mathbb{T}, X^*)\subseteq\left(L^1(\mathbb{T},X)\right)^*$$

(where $X^*$ denotes the dual space of $X$).

Comment: You didn't write what $X$ is, I can guess that $X$ is a Banach space and $ \mathbb{T}$ denotes the unit circle, right?

Comment: Exactly, that's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This duality holds if and only if $X^*$ has the Radon-Nikodym property with respect to the Haar measure on $\mathbb{T}$ which is equivalent to having the Radon-Nikodym property with respect to the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval. This is Theorem 1 on p. 98 in

> J. Diestel and J.J. Uhl, *Vector  measures*. Mathematical Surveys, Vol. 15,
>   Amer. Math. Soc., Providence (1977).

As soon as $X^*$ has RNP (for example  this is the case if $X$ is reflexive), you proceed like in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/396278/17929).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check there the proof!